# Using Rolle's theorem prove that if $b^2<3ac$, then there is exactly one root to $f(x) \equiv ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

> Using Rolle's theorem prove that if $b^2<3ac$, then there is exactly one
>   root to $f(x) \equiv ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$

I literally have no idea how to use Rolle's Theorem.

> Rolle's Theorem: if the function $f \in C[a,b]$
>    and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then there exists $c \in (a,b)$ for which $f'(c)=0$.

What I did so far:

$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$,

$D=4b^2-12ac>4b^2-4b^2=0 \implies f'(x)=0$ has exactly two roots.

If I use given inequality, I don't prove anything what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked at a similar example [Prove that if ab > 0 then the equation $ax^3 + bx + c = 0$ has exactly one root by Rolle's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954835/prove-that-if-ab-0-then-the-equation-ax3-bx-c-0-has-exactly-one-root) but I didn't find it a lot helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If $b^2 <3ac$,then  your derivative  $$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c $$ does not have a real root.

On the other hand if $f(x)=0$ had more that one real solutions, according to the Roll's theorem its derivative had to have at least one real root between those two.
Therefor  $f(x)$ has only one real root.

Note that a third degree polynomial always have at least one real root because of its  end behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis implies that $a \neq 0$. If $a >0$ then  $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ so there is at least one root. Similar argument works for $a <0$.

If there are two roots then $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$. But the  quadratic $3ax^{2}+2bx+c=0$ does not have any real roots since $4b^{2}-12ac=4(b^{2}-3ac)<0$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, there is a mistake:

if $b^2 - 3ac < 0$ (the same as your inequality), then $D=4b^2 - 12ac = 4(b^2 - 3ac) < 0$, so the derivative has no real roots.